# Find $ \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} A_{n,x}$ for $A_{n,x} = \{z \in \mathbb{R}: |n-z|>|x-z|\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The family of sets $\langle A_{n,x}: n \in \mathbb{Z}, x \in \mathbb{R} \rangle $ is given by:  $A_{n,x} = \{z \in \mathbb{R}: |n-z|>|x-z|\}$ find:
$$ \bigcap\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} A_{n,x}$$

My idea was to show that the answer is $\emptyset$. I thought that I can just take n = z to make the first module equal to $0$. Then I need my second module to be not equal to $0$, but now I see that there are values z equal to x that solve the inequaluty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $n \in \mathbb N, x \in \mathbb R$, the set $A_{n,x}$ is all the points that are closer to $x$ than they are to $n$. Take any point $z \in \mathbb R$ with $z \neq n$. Then there is some $x^* \in \mathbb R$ such that $z$ is closer to $x$ than $n$, and so $z \in A_{n,x^*}$. By contrast, the point $n$ itself is always at least as close to $n$ as it is to any other $x$, and so $n \not \in A_{x,n}$ for any $x$. Therefore $$ B_n := \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R} A_{x,n} = \mathbb R \setminus \{n\}.$$ That is, the inner union is all points except $n$. Then when you take the intersection of all $B_n$, you remove every integer $n$, and so $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb Z} B_n = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb Z} \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb R} A_{n,x} = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Z.$$

Comment: "By contrast, the point $n$ itself is always at least as close to $n$ as it is to any other $x$, and so $n \notin A_{x,n}$ for any $x$". Could you explain that part a bit more?

Comment: Oh, never mind. I think I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: First show that

$$A_{n,x}=\begin{cases}
\left(\leftarrow,\frac{n+x}2\right),&\text{if }x<n\\
\varnothing,&\text{if }x=n\\
\left(\frac{n+x}2,\to\right),&\text{if }x>n\,.
\end{cases}$$

Then show that

$$\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R}A_{n,x}&=\bigcup_{x<n}\left(\leftarrow,\frac{n+x}2\right)\cup\bigcup_{x>n}\left(\frac{n+x}2,\to\right)\\
&=(\leftarrow,n)\cup(n,\to)\\
&=\Bbb R\setminus\{n\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Once you’ve done that, it’s not too hard to see what $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\Bbb Z}\bigcup\limits_{x\in\Bbb R}A_{n,x}$ is.